# Send and receive opencv images flask

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I am trying to send and receive openCV images form client to server and back to client after processing. I am not able to understand the what type of data is being sent back by the server ...

Server:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response, send_file
import jsonpickle
import numpy as np
import cv2

import ImageProcessingFlask

# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)


# route http posts to this method
@app.route('/api/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    r = request
    # convert string of image data to uint8
    nparr = np.fromstring(r.data, np.uint8)
    # decode image
    img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    # do some fancy processing here....

    img = ImageProcessingFlask.render(img)


    #_, img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
    #print ( img_encoded)

    cv2.imwrite( 'new.jpeg', img)


    #response_pickled = jsonpickle.encode(response)
    #return Response(response=response_pickled, status=200, mimetype="application/json")
    return send_file( 'new.jpeg', mimetype="image/jpeg", attachment_filename="new.jpeg", as_attachment=True)

# start flask app
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

Client:

```
import requests
import json
import cv2

addr = 'http://localhost:5000'
test_url = addr + '/api/test'

# prepare headers for http request
content_type = 'image/jpeg'
headers = {'content-type': content_type}

img = cv2.imread('lena.jpeg')
# encode image as jpeg
_, img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)

# send http request with image and receive response
response = requests.post(test_url, data=img_encoded.tostring(), headers=headers)



print response


cv2.imshow( 'API', response.content )
```

The print statement puts out

```
<Response [200]>
```

The error is ...

```
    cv2.imshow( 'API', response.content )
TypeError: mat is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

I am new to flask, please help me solve this error.

Thank you.

Comment: I think `response.content` is JPEG-encoded, so you wiill need to `cv2.imdecode()` it before you can `cv2.imshow()` it.

Comment: `image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(response.content, dtype=np.uint8), -1)`
This returned None after printing image

Comment: I encoded the image and sent it back to the client as a json request. At the client side, decode this response using base64.b64decode(response) and lastly cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(image, np.uint8), 1) to get the image.

Comment: Thanks Mark Setchell

Comment: use scipy.misc.imread instead for reading images. It has no problems like cv2. However, response time is slower for scipy than cv2. Are u able to find the solution for this ?

Comment: Yes ... I encoded the processed image on server side ( similar to what the client did) and sent it as response.  Then receive this response and decode the json object on client side, decode it, and display ...

Answer (score 0):

## The idea:

- Client

Use cv2.imread('lena.jpeg') to load image to numpy array.
Pickle the array to data.
Send the data with `POST` request, `multipart/form-data`

- Server

Receive the data
Pickle loads the data
And we have numpy array as same as cv2.imread('lena.jpeg')

## Here is the code:

**Serialized numpy array on Client**

```
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpeg')
serialized = pickle.dumps(frame, protocol=0)
```

**Send it with post request to server**

```
name_img = "frame.jpeg"
files = {'image': (name_img, serialized, 'multipart/form-data', {'Expires': '0'})}
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post(url, files=files)
    print("status ", r.status_code)
    return r
```

**And on server, loads it back to numpy array**

```
@app.route('/receive-frame', methods=['POST'])
def handler_receive_frame():
    timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
    file = request.files['image']
    file_path = os.path.join(save_dir, "image_" + timestamp + ".jpeg")
    # file.save(file_path)
    # cv2.imwrite(file_path, file.read())
    image_numpy = pickle.loads(file.read())
    cv2.imwrite(filename=file_path, img=image_numpy)

    print("receive file name ", file.filename)
    print("output_file_name ", file_path)
    result = {"error": 0}
    return result
```

And we have `image_numpy` on server is same as `img` on client (it is an numpy array).

Whatever you want to do with `img = cv2.imread('lena.jpeg')`, you can do with `image_numpy`