# Sending and Receiving Images to Flask App

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, flask

I have build a Docker container with a Flask app running inside which takes JPG image as input and should a processed image as output. The following is the server side and client side codes:

**Server Side Code**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file,jsonify
import cv2
import numpy as np
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/add_face', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_face():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #  read encoded image
        imageString = base64.b64decode(request.form['img'])

        #  convert binary data to numpy array
        nparr = np.fromstring(imageString, np.uint8)

        #  let opencv decode image to correct format
        image2 = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR);

    return jsonify({'msg': 'success', 'size': [image2.width, image2.height]})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=False, port=5000)
```

**Client Side Code**

```
import requests
import base64
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

URL = "http://localhost:5000/add_face"

#  first, encode our image with base64
with open("Image2.jpg", "rb") as imageFile:
    img = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())

response = requests.post(URL, data={"name":"Trump", "img":str(img)})
print(response.content)
```

However this results in the following error:

```
b'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">\n<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>\n<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>\n<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>\n'
```

The Docker logs is given below:

```
main.py:17: DeprecationWarning: The binary mode of fromstring is deprecated, as it behaves surprisingly on unicode inputs. Use frombuffer instead
  nparr = np.fromstring(imageString, np.uint8)
[2020-07-13 13:26:31,483] ERROR in app: Exception on /add_face [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "main.py", line 24, in add_face
    return jsonify({'msg': 'success', 'size': [image2.width, image2.height]})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'width'
172.17.0.1 - - [13/Jul/2020 13:26:31] "POST /add_face HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Is there any issue in sending or receiving this image? Also, can I use something similar to the code below to return the processed image back as response:

```
return send_file(image2,
        attachment_filename='image.jpg',
        mimetype='image/jpg')
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: please ask only one question at a time. As for your error message. It clearly says that you receive a `None` as a resujlt for  `image2 = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR);`  - I do not know what a `cv2` is - please make sure you handle the program correctly.

Comment: cv2 is OpenCV. That's what my question is: Why is it returning a None. Is there an issue regarding the encodings?

Comment: Another similar problem posted here but the solution is not provided in full: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48465739/send-and-receive-opencv-images-flask

Comment: is it working outside of Docker?

Comment: No. It is not working. Tried the other solution given in the link. Throws the following error:---> 19 cv2.imshow( 'API', response.content )

TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'